# How do I disable the “Add to My Links” option on a list Actions Menu in 2010?

Tags: 2010

We have a SharePoint 2010 implementation and we have disabled 'User Profile'.  Now when 'Add a Link' from the menu is selected an error is thrown.

How can we hide the 'Add to My Links' option on the menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery if you are comfortable with it. You can find out the item using developer tool bar and then simply disable/hide the item you want from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.estruyf.be/blog/add-the-my-links-functionality-as-in-sharepoint-2007-to-your-2010-site/

and check

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcustomization/thread/ca593f45-b799-49ae-9b74-3e7e770af11b

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 does not contain any "Add to my Links" option, did you made any custom solution to add the option in the menu? If yes, simply uninstall/deactivate the custom solution..